# graphite: how to get per-second metrics from batch metrics?

Tags: graphite

I'm trying to measure a online mini-batch processing system with a per-second metrics (total query per second). For every batch, a metric (e.g. `"stats.gauges.<host>.query.count"`) will be send to graphite. batches are processed in several different hosts in parallel and a batch of data take about 5 seconds to process.
I've tried:

1. simply sum series: `sumSeries(stats.gauges.*.query.count)`, 
   the result metrics is many times greater than the actual value;
2. scale    to 1 second:
   `scaleToSeconds(sumSeries(stats.gauges.*.query.count),
   1)`, the result metrics is much less than the actual value;
3. integral then derivative: `nonNegativeDerivative(sumSeries(integral(stats.gauges.*.query.count)))`, same as the first case ...
4. send gauges with
   `delta=True` param, then derivative. the result is about 20% greater 
   than the actual value

so, how to get per-second metrics from batch metrics? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You should use carbon-aggregator service to add several metrics together as they come in. There is an example which fits your case at http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf

As your batch takes 5 secs to process, frequency should be 5 to buffer all the metrics. After five seconds, aggregator will sum them up and write to graphite.